# How to reset Drupal's content cache / deleted content?

Tags: 7, database, caching

I'm working with Drupal 7.44. I created some content, but then deleted those articles. However, when I go to add new content, Drupal still recognizes the title of my articles that I deleted (as I'm typing it appears as an autocomplete below the field). I'm not sure if this is still completely stored in the database or if it's just cached somewhere. How do I go about deleting this (preferably without completely having to re-install everything)?

Administration -> Configuration -> Development -> Performance and "Clear all caches" did not seem to work.

Thanks!!

Comment: This is not in Drupal at all.  It is in your browser cache.  Clear that and it will be fine or look in a new web browser.

Comment: @heart.cooks.mind Yes - that was the issue! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are using some module that I havent heard of (certainly possible) to give autocomplete style info as you are entering a node title, then I think the functionality you are describing is actually something being done by your browser.

You can alter your form to add automcomplete="off" to your title field (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag)

Comment: yes, you're correct. Checked it in another browser and it does not appear. Thanks!